# PostgreSQL error : 22007 invalid_datetime_format

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a program that is dependant on PostgreSQL, It is suddenly giving me the error

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "00:00:01."
LINE 1: ...:55:02.027392', '00:00:00.042608', '00:55:02.07', '00:00:01....
```

It occurred after loading some data into a folder that is monitored for changes to update the database. I have since removed ALL the data from that folder. I have searched for several hours, I am unable to find anything giving me direction where to start.

**postgresql-9.1-main.log**

```
2015-04-05 12:26:15 EDT ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "00:00:01." at character 234
2015-04-05 12:26:15 EDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO cc_schedule (starts, ends, cue_in, cue_out, fade_in, fade_out, clip_length, position, instance_id, file_id, stream_id) VALUES ('2015-04-06 17:00:00.000000', '2015-04-06 17:55:02.027392', '00:00:00.042608', '00:55:02.07', '00:00:01.', '00:00:01.', '00:55:02.027392', 0, 25, 1717, null) RETURNING id
```

I would appreciate any advice. I am thinking there is just a bungled entry somewhere that could be removed? or do I need to reinstall PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I had changed a configuration as related to Track Fade time. When doing so from "0.50" to "1." leaving . at the end bungled it.  Thank You for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 3):

you have two time entries with a dot at the end of time, that cause the error:

```
00:00:01.
```

fix the data to

```
00:00:01
```

Comment: Is there a preferred way to edit entries? PHPMyAdmin, Command line? I am familiar with MySQL but not PostgreSQL.  Thank You

Comment: since the data could not be written to the database, you have to edit the SQL file that you used as source. Here you could use any text editor that supports *search and replace*, then you could do a *replace all* search